# Babel Arabic + bidi crashes Make4ht + PdfLaTex in TexStudio

Tags: pdftex, babel, tex4ht, arabic, make4ht

I'm trying to convert a multi-language document (Arabic, Russian, English) into an HTML or an ODT.

I call `make4ht dummy.tex`, either from the command line or a TexStudio custom command.

`dummy.tex` contains the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references/references.bib}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,russian,british, bidi=default]{babel}
\usepackage[encapsulated]{CJK}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{booktabs,cfr-lm, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\newcommand{\righthalfring}{\begingroup\arabfalse\transtrue
    \raisebox{1pt}{\scalebox{1}[1.3]{\RL{'}}\kern-3pt}\endgroup}

\newunicodechar{ʾ}{\righthalfring}

\title{Pav's Thesis}
\author{Pavel Gudoshnikov}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \input{chapters/dummy-1/dummy-1}
\end{document}
```

The contents of the `dummy-1` file are:

```
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{My section}
\subsection{My subsection}
some text
```

This results in a failed run:

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: dummy.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)

entering extended mode

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)

entering extended mode

[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    811  Missing \endcsname inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    5    Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    5    Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    5    Undefined control sequence.
...
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    5    Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    5    Undefined control sequence.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

I can trace the "undefined control sequence" to the last two entries in the .xref file.

```
\:CrossWord{)F1F-}{dummy.html}{1}%
\:CrossWord{TITLE+}{Pav's Thesis}{1}%
\:CrossWord{)M1x0}{;}{1}%
\:CrossWord{)Qx1-10001}{1}{2}%
\:CrossWord{)Qx1-2000\protect \bgroup \o:beginL: \protect \edef T1{T1}\let \enc@update \relax \xdef \T1/clm2j/m/n/12 {\T1/clm2j/m/n/12 }\T1/clm2j/m/n/12 \size@update \enc@update \def T1{T1}1.1\o:endL: \egroup }{1}{2}%
\:CrossWord{)Qx1-3000\protect \bgroup \o:beginL: \protect \edef T1{T1}\let \enc@update \relax \xdef \T1/clm2j/m/n/12 {\T1/clm2j/m/n/12 }\T1/clm2j/m/n/12 \size@update \enc@update \def T1{T1}1.1.1\o:endL: \egroup }{1}{2}%
```

I'm completely new to shell scripting. I've read the make4ht manual. I've googled around. I've been at this for hours... Nothing short of getting rid of `arabic` and `bidi=default` seems to help.

I've tried playing around with the phrasing of the babel instructions and compiling using LuaLaTex, but that breaks things other ways. If at all possible, I would like to do this using PdfLaTex. It looks like doing this in either LuaLaTex or XeLaTex would involve considerable amounts of rewriting at the other end (about 150 pages!).

Can anyone help? I'd be massively thankful.

Comment: arabtex is from 2003, arabic.ldf (loaded by babel) from 2006. Both are unmaintained. Getting this to work would imho require much more time than switching a document to lualatex.

Comment: I am on mobile, so I cannot test what is going on. You can try to include some packages conditionally only when you don't use make4ht. Try /ifdefined/HCode/else ... Code for pdflatex /fi (i cannot use backslahses, so replace slashes with them). In general, you can try to not use inputenc, fontenc and babel. Compile document with make4ht -l option, this should work with arabic. Problems can be also with cleveref, it clashes quite often with TeX4ht